# ArrayList Remove without Collections or Imports

Tags: java

I have implemented this two methods to remove elements from the front and the back. I am not able to figure where am I doing wrong but I am failing test on either method

```
public T removefirst() {
if (size == 0) {
       return null;
    }
    T removed = backingArray[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
        backingArray[i] = backingArray[i + 1];
    }
    size--;
    return removed;
}

public T removelast() {

    if (size == 0) {
        return null;
    }

   T removed = backingArray[size - 1];
    backingArray[size - 1] = null;
    size--;
    return removed;


  }
```

Comment: How is it failing? What debugging have you done? What's the expected result vs the actual result? We need more information.

Comment: Running Junit Test provided in HW  arrays first differed at element [5]; 
Expected :null
Actual   :5a

Comment: In `removefirst()` you're using `size()` (method call) as your loop limit instead of `size`(member field access) like everywhere else; that's wrong unless `size()` always just returns `size`.  Also, if `size()` happens to return the exact size of `backingArray`, you'll get a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` from `backingArray[i + 1]`.  `removelast()` seems OK to me; no obvious error stands out...

Comment: @MLuser And what debugging have you done? And you stepped through the code while it's running to see where it goes wrong?

Comment: I am using provided Junit tests and all my tests are passing except for these two methods

Comment: Error seems obvious. In `removelast()` you null out the removed element in the `backingArray`. In `removefirst()` you don't null out anything, and the unit test error says `at element [5]; Expected :null Actual :5a`. It's expecting that you nulled out the newly cleared element of the array. So do it!

Answer (score 0):

In removeFirst Method, correct the for loop. You need to run till size-1

```
for (int i = 0; i < size()-1; i++) {
  backingArray[i] = backingArray[i + 1];
}
```

removeLast suppose to be working fine as expected.